# Reactants in high temperature chemical vapour deposition

Tags: electrolysis, carbon-family

I'm setting up a high-temperature electrolysis rig for the purpose of chemical vapour distribution.

The molten carbonate (750 degrees Celsius) will be lithium carbonate. The cathode will be galvanised steel with the anode being nickel. Nitrogen, carbon dioxide and water vapour will be fed in with the intention of splitting the carbon dioxide as a low voltage, high current is passed through the electrodes.

I'm anticipating that the carbon dioxide splits, but I am not sure how the nitrogen and water vapour will react under those conditions. I'm guessing the nitrogen won't react, but how would the water vapour react? Ideally, I'd rather not have to go to the trouble of using pure/near-pure carbon dioxide.

Thanks in advance!